# Python rotating logger, how to keep restarts from overwriting the log file?

Tags: python, logging

I'm using a rotating logger create a log file every hour

```
import logging
import logging.config
import logging.handlers

tmppath = path.abspath(path.join(path.dirname(__file__), '..', '..', 'logging.ini'))
logging.config.fileConfig(tmppath)
logger = logging.getLogger("main.main")
```

The logging.ini contains these rules which say to use the file name
*/var/log/myprogram/main.log* and to start a new file every hour.

```
[loggers]
keys=root,main

[handlers]
keys=fileHandler, consoleHandler

....

[handler_fileHandler]
class=logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler
formatter=myFormatter
args=('/var/log/myprogram/main.log', 'm', 60, 336, )
[formatter_myFormatter]
format=%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s
datefmt=
```

This logger works great and creates a file per hour.

The problem is, when the program is **restarted**, the current log file 
"/var/log/myprogram/main.log" is **overwritten**, so I lose some log time.

I could try to find the log file before activating logging and try to rename it "manually", but that seems really hacky.

Is there a way to configure logging to never overwrite a log file, but always append?

For my use case it would be acceptable, if after a restart the logging period is longer than an hour.

Comment: this is happening to me too, not just overwritten, but also for sometime after restarting, it logs wrong date and time

Comment: Did you solve the issue? I am struggling with the same problem..

Comment: @Vladiks yes/no, I now use https://pypi.org/project/logzero which makes it easier to avoid these problems